Find the Laurent expansion of $f(z) = \sin{\frac{1}{z(z-1)}}$ in $0<|z-1|<1$
Here is my idea:
$\sin{\frac{1}{z(z-1)}} = \sin{\left( \frac{-1}{z} + \frac{1}{z-1}\right)} = \sin{\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z}\right)} = \sin{\frac{1}{z-1}}\cos{\frac{1}{z}} - \cos{\frac{1}{z-1}}\sin{\frac{1}{z}}$
Then, I tried to expand sin and cos functions but it seems it is not the way as I will obtain product of series.

"I will obtain product of series." -- Why is this a problem? The Cauchy product will reduce them to a single series.

Hint
You can do composition of power series, using Faà di Bruno's formula.  If $f=\sum a_nx^n, g=\sum b_nx^n,$ then $f(g(x))=\sum c_nx^n,$ where $$c_n=\sum_{i\in \mathcal C_n}a_kb_{i_1}\dots b_{i_k},$$ with $\mathcal C_n=\{(i_1,\dots,i_k):1\le k\le n, i_1+\dots+i_k=n\}.$
Note:  you can do this because the inner power series (which you can expand) $\frac 1{z-1}-\frac 1z$ has no constant term.
